# Adding json data to postgresql with ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net, json, postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to change the coordinate information of the garden table to hold json data in the database I created with Postgresql. But when I do a `post` operation in my API, I get the following error when calling `_dbcontext.Save()`:

> PostgresException: 22P02: invalid input syntax for type json
>
> DETAIL: Detail redacted as it may contain sensitive data. Specify 'Include Error Detail' in the connection string to include this information

Models:

```
public class Garden
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public int tenant_id { get; set; }
    public int land_id { get; set; }
    public int garden_area { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public string coordinate { get; set; }
}
```

Controllers:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostOneGarden([FromBody] Garden garden)
{
    _manager.GardenService.CreateOneGarden(garden);
    return StatusCode(201, garden);
}
```

CreateOneGarden?

```
   public Garden CreateOneGarden(Garden garden)
    {
        if (garden == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        _manager.GardenRepository.CreateOneGarden(garden);
        _manager.Save();
        return garden;
    }
```

GardenRepository

```
public void CreateOneGarden(Garden garden) => Create(garden);
```

Comment: Hi,@pln,could you show the codes inside GardenService.CreateOneGarden() method?

Comment: i added in question @RuikaiFeng

Comment: Still, it is hard to know the details of the root cause, without providing a minimal, reproducible example. Have you checked whether you had serialized the object to JSON correctly?